# MacOs - Show notifications summary when do not disturb mode is disabled

Tags: macos, notifications, applescript, macos-catalina, macos-monterey

### The problem

I suffer from Slack and e-mail notification distractions at work. Currently, I have the "do not disturb" mode enabled for 8 hours a day, which covers my work time. It work's pretty well but I need to remember to check Slack messages from time to time. **And here's the problem itself, because sometimes I forgot to check Slack, and at work, I am obliged to write back after at least one hour or one and a half-hour.**

### What I've tried already

I use the MacOs spaces feature so on my Desktop 1 I always have the Slack app only. I created an automated AppleScript that once every hour is switching my current space view to Desktop 1. but unfortunately, that script contains a repeat loop which was very inefficient and caused CPU usage of 100%. No idea why, but some people on StackOverflow said these scripts are very inefficient and the language itself is designed for simple, not recurring tasks.

### What I wish I had

**Is it possible on MacOS (I'm using Monterey 12.1) to somehow display notifications summary every time I disable "do not disturb" mode?**

It would be super helpful because I would be able to create a schedule of DND mode, to enable it every hour for 59 minutes and then disable it for one minute to display all notifications straight into my face

Comment: Would setting the do not disturb focus to allow Slack notifications be an acceptable solution? [Example](https://ibb.co/k1HMR2r)

Comment: @DrZoo no, this in unacceptable. I don't want to hear that sound while coding and working :) That's the problem :) I want to check notification periodically